# Reducing entry letters using tkinter not working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The entry widget in my programme for numbers is working correctly to only allow a maximum of 3 numbers while I tried to do the same thing in a different entry widget but for characters the limit isn't working, I've got no clue why. Do you have to it in a different way since you're using letters?

Here is my code:

```
def only_letters_max_86(action, char):
if action == "1":
    # a character is inserted (deletion is 0) allow the insertion 
    # only if the inserted character char is a letter
    return char.isalpha() and len(char) <= 86
else:
    # allow deletion
    return True

def only_numbers_max_3(action, new_text):
if action == "1":
    return new_text.isdigit() and len(new_text) <= 3
else:
    return True


def main():

validate_letter = window.register(only_letters_max_86)
validate_nb = window.register(only_numbers_max_3)

label = Label(window, width = 30, background = 'lightgreen', text='enter temperature, only numbers')
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry_tempp = Entry(window, width = 30, validate="key", validatecommand=(validate_nb, '%d', '%P'))
entry_tempp.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

#create another label and entry object for location

label_numb = Label(window, width = 30, background = 'lightgreen', text='enter location, only letters')
label_numb.grid(row=1, column=0)

entry_locations = Entry(window, width = 30, validate="key", validatecommand=(validate_letter, '%d', '%S', '%v'))
entry_locations.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

Comment: Your two uses of `validatecommand=` are specifying a different number of parameters to be passed to the validation function, but your functions both take only two parameters...

Comment: @Dane if my response did the trick, would you please mark it as the accepted answer for me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:
`entry_locations = Entry(window, width = 30, validate="key", validatecommand=(validate_letter, '%d', '%S', '%v'))`

You are passing `'%S'` to your `validate_letter` function which looking at the docs means:

> '%S': If the call was due to an insertion or deletion, this argument will be the text being inserted or deleted.

So my guess is that `char` in `only_letters_max_86(action, char)` only gets the character that is being inserted which will always be of length one, causing your check to fail. Try changing `%S` to `%P`which gives you:

> '%P': The value that the text will have if the change is allowed.

Link to the docs: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html

Comment: Sadly this didn't fix the problem, thank you though. The link contained lots of helpful information!

Comment: Nevermind, I was using a different version of the programme. Thank you very much!